# On click повторяет вызов

Tags: jquery, javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста почему событие on click  повторяется.
Тоесть, когда открывается модальное окно и мы попадаем в событие:

```
$(document).on("click", ".confirm-success", function(event)
```

Оно вызывается несколько раз. Причем если открывать и закрывать окно и нажмимать на кнопку, то событие будет вызываться каждый раз на 1 раз больше.

```
    $("body").on("click", ".ConfirmPostRequestToServer", function() 
    {  
        // данные самого окна 
        var box_modal_id = getNewId();
        var c = $('<div class="box-modal" />');
            c.prepend('<div class="box-modal_close arcticmodal-close">X</div>');
            c.attr('id', box_modal_id);

        // MODAL-CONFIRM
        var button = '';
            button += '<div class="box-modal-confirm-button">';
            button += '<button class="large green awesome confirm-success">Подтвердить</button>';
            button += ' &nbsp;  &nbsp; <button class="large awesome arcticmodal-close">Отмена</button>';
            button += '</div><div class="modal-loader"></div>';

            c.html('Предупреждение'+button);
            var arcticmodalData = {content: c};

        $.arcticmodal(arcticmodalData);

        $(document).on("click", ".confirm-success", function(event){

            event.preventDefault();

            console.log(1);

            return false;
        });

        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Так зачем делать в одном событии другое?

Comment: для меня по читабельности кода удобнее, больше незачем. А есть разница ?

Comment: вы добавляете обработчик события при каждом вызове click на .ConfirmPostRequestToServer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Событие внутри нужно вынести и удалить оттуда `return false;` - у вас ведь уже есть `event.preventDefault();` 
А ещё можно приращение button сделать одной строкой:
    `button += '<div class="box-modal-confirm-button"><button class="large green awesome confirm-success">Подтвердить</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="large awesome arcticmodal-close">Отмена</button></div><div class="modal-loader"></div>';`